# What is the distinction and unit of the number written in the slope field

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, 3d-analyst, slope, surface

I added a line shapefile to a surface using the Arc map 10.3
In order to calculate the 3D length and slope  of each feature line
The result was as in the picture.

[image]

What is the distinction or the unit of the number written in the slope field?

How can I read it or convert it to a slope degree?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, slopes in ArcMap are always calculated in either degrees or percent. Since the highest a degree slope can be is 90 degrees, and your slope value is 587, yours must be in percent. I'm guessing you used the [Add Surface Information](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/add-surface-information.htm) tool, which according to the [help](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/add-surface-information.htm) produces slope results in percent:

> Slope values are measured in percentage units (grade) and, for line
>   features, get calculated at each segment along the line.